# Fragment and ListFragment incompatibility

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have this method that launches a page when I select it from a menu. The problem is that some of these extend `Fragment` like from case 1 to 6, while others extend `ListFragment` as in case 7.

I get a: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ItemListFragment to Fragment` error.

How do I solve this?

```
    package com.prjma.lovertech.activity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
//import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.prjma.lovertech.R;
import com.prjma.lovertech.R.array;
import com.prjma.lovertech.R.drawable;
import com.prjma.lovertech.R.id;
import com.prjma.lovertech.R.layout;
import com.prjma.lovertech.R.menu;
import com.prjma.lovertech.R.string;
import com.prjma.lovertech.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import com.prjma.lovertech.fragment.*;
import com.prjma.lovertech.model.NavDrawerItem;
import com.prjma.lovertech.util.SessionManager;

public class WallActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    // Session Manager Class
    public SessionManager session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wall);

        // Session Manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext()); 

        /**
         * Call this function whenever you want to check user login
         * This will redirect user to LoginActivity is he is not
         * logged in
         * */
        session.checkLogin();

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Messaggi
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Oggettti seguiti
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Oggetti acquistati, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // In vendita
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // Venduti
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));
        // Invenduti
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1), true, "3"));
         // ListView
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

l

```
package com.prjma.lovertech.fragment;

import com.prjma.lovertech.R;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class InvendutiFragment extends Fragment {

    public InvendutiFragment(){}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_invenduti, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

ll

```
package com.prjma.lovertech.fragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.prjma.lovertech.dummy.DummyContent;

/**
 * A list fragment representing a list of Items. This fragment also supports
 * tablet devices by allowing list items to be given an 'activated' state upon
 * selection. This helps indicate which item is currently being viewed in a
 * {@link ItemDetailFragment}.
 * <p>
 * Activities containing this fragment MUST implement the {@link Callbacks}
 * interface.
 */
public class ItemListFragment extends ListFragment {

    /**
     * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
     * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
     */
    private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

    /**
     * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
     * clicks.
     */
    private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

    /**
     * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
     */
    private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

    /**
     * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
     * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
     * selections.
     */
    public interface Callbacks {
        /**
         * Callback for when an item has been selected.
         */
        public void onItemSelected(String id);
    }

    /**
     * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
     * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
     */
    private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(String id) {
        }
    };

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public ItemListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // TODO: replace with a real list adapter.
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1, DummyContent.ITEMS));
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
        if (savedInstanceState != null
                && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
            setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState
                    .getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
        if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
        }

        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
        mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
        mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mActivatedPosition != AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
            outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
     * given the 'activated' state when touched.
     */
    public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
        // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
        // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
        getListView().setChoiceMode(
                activateOnItemClick ? AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                        : AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
    }

    private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
        if (position == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
        } else {
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        }

        mActivatedPosition = position;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give us more codes of your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    ListFragment listfragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new MessaggiFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new OggettiSeguitiFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new OggettiAcquistatiFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new InVenditaFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new VendutiFragment();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new InvendutiFragment();
        break;
    case 7:
        listfragment = new ItemListFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }     
    if (fragment != null) {
        // do stuff if it's a fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
    } else if (listfragment != null) {
        // do stuff if its a listfragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, listfragment).commit();
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
```

Comment: gives me an error: The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, ListFragment)

Comment: ListFragmnent is-a Fragment

Answer (score 8):

The only way of fixing this is to either go fully with compatibility package or stick to `android.app` classes. So either have your parent activity extending from support package `FragmentActivity`/`ActionBarActivity` and your fragments extending from compatibility - by the way, compatibility package has a `ListFragment` too.

Or, have your parent activity extending from `android.app.Activity` and all your fragments from `android.app.Fragment`.

**EDIT**: After seeing your `ItemListFragment` class I am reiterating my statement, so replace this import in `ItemListFragment`:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
```

with

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
```

Comment: on the long run which one is better?

Comment: It depends on your min SDK. If it's set to at most 10, then go with compatibility package `FragmentActivity`. If it's more, then it doesn't make sense to use compatibility package for Activity and Fragment. You will need anyway to use the compatibility package for things like `ViewPager` or `LruCache`, but not for fragment support.

Comment: i set my sdk to min of 12 till 19. could you post the code to show me? thanks!

Comment: What is the canonical class name of the parent of ItemListFragment?

Comment: @Pheonix7: edited the answer, basically my suspicion was right ... A small change in your code will put things on track