# master/detail flow inside a Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android development and have a question about an UI that I am trying to implement, and after several hours of searching and trying everything I am still stuck.

What I need is a master/detail flow inside a Navigation Drawer, something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/98pnx.jpg
(awesome paint skills)

ok, the navigation drawer is for quick navigation between the categories, and every category should have a master/detail flow and its own items (acording to the category), the posibility to add new items and the item info, every item should also be able to be deleted and this is going to be used to manage a database which is already done.

The code is rather simple, its already done on a pc version, but the interface is being a really big problem.

I used this:
[Navigation Drawer and master/detail flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290973/navigation-drawer-and-master-detail-flow)
 but  had some errors which I fixed with this: [Fragment and ListFragment incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429815/fragment-and-listfragment-incompatibility) but now I have some other errors and I just want to start over and make it right from the start.